# iOS App showing blank screen after startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

I have developed an iOS app for which I had set the target to iOS 5. But then I wanted to set the target to 4.3, so I changed it in Project>Summary>Deployment Target. The code starts up and works fine in iOS 5. But when I try to run it on a device with iOS 4.3, it just shows the startup image and then a black screen. It doesn't even run the code. Can anyone tell me what might be happening?

Comment: Are you useing xib files or stroyboars?

Comment: Storyboards are supported for Versions over 5(i.e. 5.X..) Since App delegate cant find any supported view object(the nibs), you are faced with a blank screen..

Comment: I see, so to support 4.3 and above, I must use only xib files?

Comment: yup XIB will work for lower version.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like I'll have to make some drastic changes to my app to support iOS below 5.0. Do you guys think this is worth it? Or should I just stick to my target for 5.0 and above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right, storyboards are iOS5.0 and later

Comment: Hmm. I just found out. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hmm. It looks like I'll have to make some drastic changes to my app to support iOS below 5.0. Do you guys think this is worth it? Or should I just stick to my target for 5.0 and above?

Comment: I'd say, unless distribution is key, feel safe to ignore versions below iOS5.0.

Comment: @EgeAkpinar hemşerim ayıp oluyor, yorumla bırakılabilecek bir önermeye cevapvemeye gerek yok burda:)

Answer (score 0):

try this , see the below attached Image  :)
[image]

Comment: Tried it. Still no change. Do you think it has something to do with storyboards? (Sorry, I'm new to iOS)

Comment: ohh fish.. !! dats so stupid of me .. Storyboards will work for iOS 5 or Later ;  for details about storyboards check this : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html